# Play minecraft on ubuntu?

Tags: java, minecraft

So, I have downloaded and installed java multiple different ways, but I cannot get minecraft to work. I really don't know what's going on, so I don't know how to explain it, but check out this video to see it in action: http://youtu.be/ZN9pmmjzqw0 If you would like to see the logs, they can be downloaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/?xgbxoe37gq79b

Comment: Apparently, from your logs, minecraft has been trying to write on memory that has not been allocated to it. Have you tried to command like execute it like: java /home/<username>/Home/Desktop/minecraft.jar

Comment: Nlight, when I do that, I get this: Error: Could not find or load main class .home.steven.Home.Desktop.minecraft.jar

Comment: @NlightNfotis: the command is `java -jar /home/<username>/Desktop/minecraft.jar`, or `java -jar ~/Desktop/minecraft.jar`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have installed a Windows version of Java in Wine and it takes precedence over the "normal" Java from Ubuntu repositories, possibly only when you open Minecraft via a desktop shortcut.

You need to remove the Windows version of Java (if you have no other stuff installed in Wine I'd just remove/rename `.wine` directory to be sure it's gone) and then try to run Minecraft from terminal with

```
cd ~/Desktop
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

Note the -jar parameter. Make sure you can run Minecrafr this way, and then you can create a desktop shortcut as described in the article linked to by MickStep.

You also don't need Minecraft.exe, and it won't work, don't even try.

Also, Minecraft works well for me with Ubuntu's stock-standard OpenJDK Java, so maybe you can start with it, and if it does not work look at installing Java from Oracle (but, again, not a Windows version)

Comment: Alright.. I'm honestly a major ubuntu noob (as you can most likely tell) so could you go through a detailed explination on how to get rid of the windows java?

Comment: @StevenFontaine: there should be some uninstaller somewhere in Wine (similar to what you usually have in Windows: Start - Oracle - Java blah-blah - Uninstall Java). Alternatively, running `mv ~/.wine ~/.wine.old` will effectively clear all your Wine install. However, I now think that running `java` in terminal still invokes the system Java, so you can just ignore the Windows version and try typing the commands from my answer in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have installed the icedtea version of Java which is free software, however it appears you need to have the proprietary version of java to run minecraft, check out this blog post:

http://corbindavenport.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-play-minecraft-on-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: Spot on! Did not notice the Icedtea java. How could I have missed it? +1

Comment: I followed the instructions completely, but, when I try to open the file I created, nothing happens. No logs appear, no errors pop up, nothing.... :(

Comment: Also, what is the proprietary version of java? Chances are I've installed it. I swear, I've installed java 20 different ways trying to fix this! D:

Comment: @StevenFontaine: Ironically, installing 20 different versions of Java is not going to improve your chances to run Minecraft :) I'd suggest to try to remove ALL of them (i.e. make sure typing `java` in terminal results in "command not found") and then install just one Java from Ubuntu repos. Otherwise you have a soup of different Java versions which step on each other feet.

Comment: OpenJDK 6 works fine here with Minecraft...

Comment: Another poor mistaken person. You DON'T need to install Oracle Java. -1.